# Pandas Dataframe asFreq changing datatype of index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having an issue when using asfreq to resample a dataframe.  My dataframe, df, has an index of type Datetime.Date().  After using df.asfreq('d','pad'), my dataframe index has been changed to type pandas.tslib.Timestamp.  I've tried the following to change it back but I'm having no luck...

```
df = df.set_index(df.index.to_datetime())
df.index =  df.index.to_datetime()
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

This is the canonical approach to creating datetime indices.  If you want your index indices to all be of type `datetime.datetime` then you can do this following.

```
df.index = pd.Index([i.to_datetime() for i in df.index], name=df.index.name, dtype=object)
```

I just don't know why you'd want to.

Comment: no dice.  When you convert the index to a list after this, you can see that it's still a timestamp : Timestamp('2016-09-15 00:00:00', offset='D'),

Comment: The reason I want it to be datetime is I have a number of get_value pulls later on, and I don't want to track whether an index has turned to timestamp or dateframe

Comment: @keynesiancross whatever your reasons... was my answer useful?

Comment: trying it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Why is this a problem? If you really need a `datetime.date` you can try `df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x.date()` since `pandas.TimeStamp` subclasses `datetime.datetime`